# Sanity check: Torque requirement to overcome the effect of multiple forces acting on a lever

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram

The only way I could describe the problem is with a few pictures; but there are three questions arising, and I'm looking for confirmation or correction of my approach; rather than a solution to the simplified sample problem in the image below.

A mechanism like this:[![Eccentric cam and multiple followers imparting variable forces
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LAbJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LAbJ.png)

The multiple cam followers(purple) each impart a variable force on the cam (orange circle), as it rotates on its eccentric stub axle(small yellow circle) around the concentric axle (large yellow circle).

[image: Exploded view of the cam, eccentric axle and concentric housing]

As the concentric input axle rotates clockwise, the action of the eccentric stub axle and the meshing gears, causes the cam to rotate anti-clockwise.

My goal is given the forces acting on the cam followers, work out how much torque is required to rotate the cam.

I think this is the right approach:
[image: Summing of forces, levers and torque]

Q1) If I sum the X-components and the Y-components of all the forces acting, I get the resultant force acting on the stub axle?

Q2) At any given point in the rotation, the combined action of the eccentric axle lever arm, and the meshing gears constrains the movement normal to the eccentric axle lever angle?

Q3) Only that component of the resultant force acting in that normal direction needs to be countered? Any other component to the force will be "absorbed" by the gear teeth and bearings.

Comment: No responses? Time of year; question to complicated; other reason(s)?

Comment: What a waste of my time! What a pathetic reasoning for  deeming "off-topic". What stupefyingly limited mental faculties you people have. Anything with "stackexchange" in the url == pedants glorifying in finding reasons why they can't (be bothered) to answer the question asked.